# PHP: Show an actual image when getting read receipt

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

So I am working on getting an email read receipt (Laravel and PHP), where I try to update a field in DB when an email is opened. 
**Description**
1. Send an email to a user.
2. Once that user reads the mail, update the message status from "unread" to "read" in the database.

**Code I have already added to make it happen**
1. Send message id to mail body.
2. Add `<img>` tag like,

```
<p><img src="http://www.xyzdomain.com/messagestatus/{{$id}}"></p>
```

3. Have a function in controller with route for above url, which will do the DB update for me.

**Problem**
Though the status is successfully updated to "Read" when a user reads that mail. The image shown in mail body is broken because i am passing a url and not image. Can someone guide me about how can I show some image like some transparent background image which won't show a broken image.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. So if the URL is not going to an image why include it in the `src` in the first place ? If they would all be the same image why not just place that image in the `src` (`<img src="http://www.xyzdomain.com/someImage.png">`) other than the URL?

Comment: Maybe you din't understand my question or maybe I din't understand your confusion. I am trying to update my system's DB when a user opens an email, i send a message id via url in the `img` tag. Like you mentioned, the image will be same all the time, the logic behind using `img` tag is as soon as the mail is opened it will execute the function behind that url on my system and update DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect to an image file after the DB update.. for example, create an image in this url:

> http://www.xyzdomain.com/img.png

(Preferably a 1x1 px transparent image)

Then after your DB update redirect using `header()` to this image file.

```
<?php

   ... some db updating code ...

   header('Location: http://www.xyzdomain.com/img.png');
   die();

 ?>
```

This way, the image will not be broken in your client's email. It will actually get an image file after updating the database.

Comment: Worked.! thanks so much. I was confused on this part. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a redirect if you just return the content of the image (a small 1x1 transparent image) after making an update:

```
<?php
$image = 'image.png';
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile($image);
exit;
```

Of course, you have to return right `mime` type.